# Write Extracted values to csv or text Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I am trying to write extracted values from session to the csv file in a scala gatling script , I am extracting multiple fields and need to write data to multiple columns in csv . Can someone please suggest how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session` to first save all the required values and later save it to the file via `exec` call:

```
exec(
...
.check(regex("data(.*?)\"").findAll.saveAs("userIds")))
)
.exec( session => {        
   scala.reflect.io.File("data.csv").appendAll(session("userIds").as[Seq[String]].mkString(",")+"\n")
   session
})
```

in example above I assume you get a list of userId and you write it in a single line.
You can check more advanced example for writing headers & rows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666231/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-in-scala)